# Keep container running after the command is stopped

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I need to fix my db in postgres database, for this I need to stop the `postgres` process, but once I stop it the `docker compose` terminates the container immediately so I can't run other commands in that container.
How to keep container on even the process from command is stopped? (was trying `tty:true`, doesn't help)

Comment: Mount the data volume on an other container running e.g. bash and fix whatever you like. Then restart your db container.

Comment: This seems very hacky. The whole purpose of containers is they are meant to be immutable, any changes you need to make should be in the container image and then just replace the running container.

Comment: But the db is stored locally. Anyway I found solution

Comment: How are you trying to fix the database?  You can't usually manually edit the database files, and you can't usually run SQL commands if the database server isn't running.  Maybe a new temporary container will help you?  (Take Docker out of the picture: you stopped the database server, what are you planning to do now?)

Comment: For example some reindexing, so I can stop the main process of postgres, then execute it in self mode and call queries there. anyway, problem solved ;) many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
command: bash -c "/docker-entrypoint.sh postgres && tail -F anything"
```

I need to use composed command, and it works now as I need